# Why doesn't the Type to Search box in the Explorer pane return all datasets?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery newbie here, trying to get comfortable and learn the ins and outs of the console.

The `bigquery-public-data` project contains 5 datasets starting with `austin` as shown below.

[image]

However, when I search, only one is returned as shown below.

[image]

I can guess that perhaps permissions are in play, however, I compared the permissions between the datasets and nothing is jumping out of me.

Can someone explain where I can look to understand what is happening?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your browser and then retying your scenario? Also, can you try to clear cache and see if something changes.

Comment: @ScottB thanks for the suggestion, however that has no impact. This is easily reproducible on different machines.

Comment: The scenario is not reproducible in my end. Have you tried testing it using other projects?

Comment: Using the "bigquery-public-data" project, if you filter for "austin", you get all 5 datasets? I've tried 2 different machines, using 2 different Google accounts and got the same results both times.

Comment: Can you try putting `%austin%` in the search bar and see if you can retrieve the correct matching?

Comment: No difference, still doesn't work. (Note, wildcards aren't necessary as the Search will match any part of the string.)

Comment: I can reproduce this in a project I control by changing permissions. Since I don't control the "bigquery-public-data" project, I'm just going to assume there is something about how security is configured on the project and/or datasets that is causing this.